# Telling a thread to wait until the SD card is mounted

Tags: android, wait, program-entry-point, sd-card

I am working on an app in which I want the main thread to wait until the SD card is mounted, in the case that it is not yet mounted. How would I do this? I was thinking of something like this:

```
while (!android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        // Wait
    }
```

But I'm worried this gives problems when someone doesn't have an SD card. Also, I don't know how to tell it to wait until the external storage state changes. It would be of great help to me if some of you can show me the right way to do this.

Comment: You musn't have the **main thread** wait, period.  You will have to re-architect so that the post-waiting tasks happen as part of a distinct event call, or do them on another thread which can wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a BroadcastReceiver and wait for the following actions:

```
android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**MyReceiver.java**:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ((Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT.equals(intent.getAction())
                || Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(intent.getAction()))
                && Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
            // Handle the SD card state changed
        }
    }
}
```